# Pandas: column counting ordered occurrence of value in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply logic depending on if a value in a column has occurred more than one time.  I got what I needed by referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667362/pandas-count-the-occurrences-of-each-value-in-column).  However, I was hoping to create a new column that looked like this:

```
Col1      Desired Column
Value1     1
Value1     2
Value2     1
Value1     3
Value2     2
Value3     1
```

Such that the 'Desired Column' is giving a count in consecutive order of the value's occurrence in Col1.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
In [1701]: df['Desired Column'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount() + 1                                                                                                                                         

In [1702]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1702]: 
     Col1  Desired Column
0  Value1               1
1  Value1               2
2  Value2               1
3  Value1               3
4  Value2               2
5  Value3               1
```